# Jquery Load Joomla Template Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla-template, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla Template that I am designing, but to help with the overall appeal/gui I would like to preload post/pages/blogs created and have them dynamically load on the front page.  Is this possible with Joomla? It works for pages that I have already created, but what about if the site has pages that are created.  Essentially allowing the front end to load a random page from a dynamically created list.  Is there a way to get a list of all pages/posts dynamically from joomla and have javascript/jquery preload this pages and or only load those pages on the main site.

Simplified Request.  A One page Website that functions as a multi page interface.  So the user has a set control interface option that will allow them to load pages without actually refreshing/loading each page each time.

Wondering if any Stack Overflow users have set up anything like this before and can provide some insight on how they accomplished this.  I understand how to pre load with pre pages, but the goal is to dynamically load them based on new pages created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know it would take quite a bit of overriding to get it to work, as joomla does not work "ajaxified" by default. I would look in the joomla extensions directory to see if there is anything like this already done. a template can possibly do this by default (I have seen something similar in wordpress)

http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=ajax

There is a number of plugins that add ajax functionality, though how closely they match what your goal is can be another matter.

To code this in yourself, you would need knowledge in jQuery/JavaScript and create the template to override links into calling pages though ajax and overriding joomla's functionality to stop it from including headers/footers in all extra pages (just the html you need).

Going further in depth would take quite some time. I recommend looking for a plugin that might do this by default, this way you won't have to spend so much time changing how joomla loads pages.

Comment: The Jquery / Javascript would not be an issue, but it is the ability to some how get Joomla to return a Json format or something similar to pass to jquery/javascript so that a list of pages that have been created in the admin panel can be preloaded.  Essentially I still want Joomla to still function the way it does on the back end, but on the design/template side load only the pages themselves.  The only way I have been able to get this to work so far is to create the pages first and then copy the link and then have jquery pre load the content that way.

Comment: This is why I suggested overrides, you can override the "view" of every component, instead dumping the data into a JSON format. I believe there is a joomla function to disable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739611/joomla-component-output-without-html that question may help with that.

Comment: I am not looking to display content any different.  I am simply looking for a way to get the entire list of links created to preload in Jquery.

Comment: It appears while looking for another aspect of the Joomla API I came across this, can anyone confirm this is what I am looking for? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957889/easy-way-to-get-params-from-joomla-menu-table